# Obscure 90's TV Show or Miniseries Involving a domed city, genetically immortal humans and mutant humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I vaguely remember watching a show in the late 80's or early 90's about this civilization that found a way to genetically alter themselves to be immortal. Unfortunately for a certain percentage of the human population, they had a regressive effect and were turned into some sort of Cro-Magnon looking proto-humans.

So the immortals secured themselves in a domed city to protect themselves from the aggressive regressives.

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate of a previously accepted question. Please note that this does not indicate a bad question, just that we've had this one before, and we want to link them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be [Island City](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110163/?ref_=tt_urv)?

This show had everything: Cities under force field bubbles, genetic engineering, mutants, bad acting, poor dialog, 90s special effects, and a pre-Batman Kevin Conroy.

> A 21st-century genetic experiment goes chaotic, creating a race of
> genetically-violent mutants.

> Attempts to produce a "fountain of youth" medication succeed, but
> trigger a recessive gene present in a large amount of the population
> which causes them to sort of devolve to the stage of Cro-Magnon man.

For the masochists amongst y'all, the entire thing is on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKPSMCc0_WI).  You've been warned.

Comment: That's it! Man, you guys are awesome lol

Comment: Excellent.  I thought I was the only one who remembered this tragedy.  @RussellWatkins please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I just watched the first few minutes of it on YouTube and it's every bit as bad as I remember it. Crappy special effects, stilted dialog. Man, the 90's were sweet lol

Comment: @RussellWatkins thanks for the YouTube reference.  Now we can share this thing with the world.