# Movie/TV show about people living in a fortress-like city, surrounded by a wasteland populated by violent, mutated humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, mutant

I am looking for what I'm pretty sure was a movie. I remember seeing it late at night in the '90s, because I had severe insomnia. People lived in this huge, fortress-like city, and outside it was a wasteland. In this wasteland, there were mutated humans who were violent. People had to have what looked like a colored glow stick on their chest to identify who they could date/have kids with, in order to prevent the children from mutating. This could have been from anywhere between the mid '80s to mid '90s.

Comment: Very probably a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60488/90s-or-earlier-scifi-movie-glowing-lights-in-chests-to-indicate-attraction

Comment: Also see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259777/obscure-90s-tv-show-or-miniseries-involving-a-domed-city-genetically-immortal/259778#259778

Comment: This sounds like an episode of The Kardashians

Comment: True, but the movie has better dialogue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [90s (or earlier) SciFi movie - glowing lights in chests to indicate attraction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60488/90s-or-earlier-scifi-movie-glowing-lights-in-chests-to-indicate-attraction)

Comment: @WoJ - typically we close story-id questions as duplicates only if both the dupe and target have the same _accepted_ answer

Comment: @fez: I thought that was the case, no?

Comment: @WoJ - This question doesn't have a confirmed answer yet (no green checkmark on the answer), so even though it is likely a dupe, [our meta-policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065) is to wait for both answers to be accepted before closing as a duplicate. This only applies to story-id questions however.

Comment: @fez: ahhh, I get it - THIS question needs to have the right accepted answer. OK, sorry. (I was frantically clicking on the suggested dupes and was wondering if I am the only one to see the same answer as accepted :) And also wondering why it is not marked as a dupe yet despite every planet being aligned. Now I understand that one of the planets is still off course (Pluto, probably))

Answer (score 12):

[Island City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_City_(1994_film)) (1994)

**In this wasteland, there were mutated humans who were violent.**

> In the future, humanity develops a "fountain of youth" drug, but as
> many people around the world begin to take it, most begin to mutate
> into a barbaric proto-humanoid state.

**People had to have what looked like a colored glow stick on their chest to identify who they could date/have kids with, in order to prevent the children from mutating.**

> Citizens of the city wear a colored crystal on their sternum based on
> the individual's genetic makeup, and can mate only with other citizens
> of the same color. Progeny resulting from people of two different
> colors would have the genetic mutation that, when combined with the
> "fountain of youth" drug, created the race of proto-humanoids.

It’s available on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKPSMCc0_WI).

Comment: Intriguing premise.  Too bad the execution didn't carry its weight.